# Nearest free coordinates in database

Tags: mysql, sql, coordinates

I have X and Z coordinates in my database. Coordinates are INTegers.

Each coordinate is bigger or equal then 0.

I need to get nearest free (not in database) coordinates to 0;0 but I don't want to limit one coordinate to specified number.

Again, I don't want to get nearest coordinate in database, I want to get nearest FREE coordinate.

This is what I did myself. But it only tells me where is free space in my coordinates square (limited by maximum X and maximum Z coordinates in database).

Problem is that I cannot select free coordinates from that. I only get distance where are free coordinates but not that coordinates.

```
SELECT distance
FROM (
    SELECT (x+z) AS distance,COUNT(owner) AS count
    FROM coordinates 
    GROUP BY x+z ASC
) AS coor
WHERE coor.distance != coor.count-1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like that:

```
select x, z
from (
    select x, z+1 as z from coordinates union all
    select x+1, z from coordinates union all
    select x+1, z+1 from coordinates union all
    select 0, 0
) as q
where
    concat(x,'_',z) not in (select concat(x,'_',z) from coordinates)
order by (x+z) asc
limit 1
```

Comment: Upvoting the clever approach :-)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem is that you're dealing with a *sparse* table, i.e., you don't have any data when the coordinate is free. If you had a tuple with a "free" flag set to true, you could just do

```
SELECT x, z FROM coordinates WHERE flagFree ORDER BY (x*x+z*z) LIMIT 1;
```

but to do that, you'd need maximumX*maximumZ records.

To find data when you have actually no data you need a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN.

One way to do that would be to prepare two tables holding the numbers from 0 to maximumX and those from 0 to maximumY. At this point,

```
 SELECT coordinates.* from maxx JOIN maxz 
      LEFT JOIN coordinates ON ( ix = x AND iz = z );
```

will yield NULL for all missing coordinates. So:

```
 SELECT ix, iz from maxx JOIN maxz 
      LEFT JOIN coordinates ON ( ix = x AND iz = z )
      WHERE x IS NULL AND z IS NULL
      ORDER BY ix*ix + iz*iz
 LIMIT 1;
```

will get you the coordinates you need.

Borrowing from Lashane's solution, you can do the same without other tables, reasoning that any *nearest* empty cell you find to the origin will be either the origin itself (0,0) or adjacent to another filled cell. And filled cells are in coordinates. So:

```
SELECT p.x, p.z FROM ( 
    SELECT 0 AS x, 0 AS z 
    UNION
    SELECT x+1, z FROM coordinates
    UNION
    SELECT x+1, z+1 FROM coordinates
    UNION
    SELECT x, z+1 FROM coordinates
) AS p 
LEFT JOIN coordinates AS a ON (p.x = a.x AND p.z = a.z)
WHERE a.x IS NULL AND a.z IS NULL
ORDER BY p.z*p.z + p.x*p.x
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Well explained, beat me to typing a long story  :)

Comment: I'm not sure that table with 2^32 or 2^64 records is reasonable space usage

Comment: Yes, for *large* sparse matrices your approach is more efficient. I've edited the answer to merge both.